# Change string to lowercase except for first character and copy to clipboard

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, pyperclip

I want to write simple lambda or function that takes a string, changes to lowercase except for the first case and copies the result to clipboard in Linux.

I have lambda:

```
to_lower = lambda s : s[0].upper() + s[1:].lower()
```

This is ok:

```
to_lower("some Sentence with Incorrect Size of characterS")
Some sentence with incorrect size of characters
```

But how I copy the result of this lambda to clipboard automatically, so that I can paste it into a text editor. At the moment, I have to manually select text in python command line to copy to clipboard.

Comment: there is [`word.title()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out pyperclip:
http://coffeeghost.net/2010/10/09/pyperclip-a-cross-platform-clipboard-module-for-python/

```
import pyperclip
pyperclip.copy('The text to be copied to the clipboard.')
```